# Firestore best practice for refering to document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to show to user items, he participated in (for example liked **posts**). Now I store in **user** **document** (in users collection) **IDs** **of** documents from another collection (**posts**) and when I want to show them in recycler view firstly I get IDs from user document. Then I get all posts by IDs. Is there any workaround, where I would be able to store user ID in subcollection of post document and then **get** **query** **of** **all** liked/commented/whatever **posts** by user? So user document will not have reference to post's IDs and in posts collection I am able to do something like:

```
Query ref = from db.collection("posts") get all posts where post.likedBy == user;
```

I do no like idea of putting all users who liked the post into post document - user downloads all ids.

```
posts (collection)
  -postID (post document)
   -authorID, ... (fields)

users (collections)
  -userID (user document)
    -string[] idsOfPosts (fields)
```

Comment: I'm not really clear on the problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried to edit question

Comment: Still unclear.  It sounds like you know what you want to do - putting user IDs in documents in a subcollection. Where are you stuck implementing it?

Comment: @DougStevenson I do not know, how then get all documents (like query) containig user ID in its subcollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) as your data model.

> Documents in subcollections can contain subcollections as well,
>   allowing you to further nest data. You can nest data up to 100 levels
>   deep.

Also you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to retrieve documents from a collection group instead of from a single collection. The link provides you with sample code snippets in different languages.

**EDIT:**

Based on the use case you have provided in the comments:

I would say the way you are describing your data model to get all posts liked by a user, it would need a query inside a query. Not sure if it's even feasible or efficient.

Here is my suggestion:
Build your data model similar to the following
[image]

This way running the following query (I'm using NodeJs) would give you all posts liked by user1.

```
let postsRef = db.collection('posts');

const user1 = postsRef.where('Liked', 'array-contains',
  'user1');

let query1 = user1.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT: (11/12/2019)**

Based on what you have described in the comments, here is an idea that might solve your issue:

Instead of having a list of the Users who liked the post, you can have a reference to a Document that contains the list of users. You can reference to as many Documents as you wish.

Example:

[image]

The Documents can be even in a different Collection.

Comment: I saw this example before, but I was not sure if it is useful for my case, because I would store in that subcollection users who liked the post, but I am curious not about the users but the document above = the post. So I would have to retrieve parent documents after getting result. And I see, that there is no clearer way  to do it.

Comment: Please state clearly what you are trying to achieve so I can try to help you further.I am not sure what exactly is the desired outcome you're trying to get.

Comment: Problem: is it possible to get all posts documents that user liked in single Query? If so, how.

Comment: @Zolo I have updated the answer based on what you described in the comments.

Comment: But problem is, that document can only have 1MB, so if there is more users it has to be stored elsewhere... and when I download that document do I have to always download all users who liked it ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a possible solution for your use-case. @Zolo